# Stuck at "Establishing an encrypted directory connection"

Tags: configuration, help, bridge

it seems that there are some problems when i try to configure the Tor connectionS:
the Bridges used in configuration are totally from "://bridges.torproject.org/bridges?transport=obfs4";
And before configuring, i've already try to Ping with those bridges, Ping is fine; But still i cannot finish the configuration,  stuck at the step of "Establishing an encrypted directory connection", and could not move on; 
Below are the snapshots during the failure, please help to troubleshoot it。

[image: stuck at this step;]

[image: ping is good; but got stuck at "Establishing an encrypted directory connection"]

below are the Logs when try to configure Tor:
*

```
2016/1/21 21:50:46.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2016/1/21 21:50:46.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2016/1/21 21:50:46.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2016/1/21 21:50:46.300 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
2016/1/21 21:50:52.700 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
2016/1/21 21:50:52.700 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
2016/1/21 21:51:13.700 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to xx.xx.xx.xx ("general SOCKS server failure") 
2016/1/21 21:51:13.700 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to xx.xx.xx.xx ("general SOCKS server failure") 
2016/1/21 22:06:13.700 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to xx.xx.xx.xx ("general SOCKS server failure") 
2016/1/21 22:06:13.700 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to xx.xx.xx.xx ("general SOCKS server failure") 
2016/1/21 22:09:47.600 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
2016/1/21 22:09:47.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2016/1/21 22:09:47.600 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
```

  *

Comment: Please don't post bridge addresses in public forums. It makes them that little bit easier for people who want to block them to find. (And defeats the point of having to request them, rather than just having them on a public wiki.)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you may be a victim of TLS/HTTPS MitM-attack, try to use **Meek** and **Obfs3/4** pluggable transports. If it won't work either - please post your Tor log here, so I'll be able to help you further. Stay tuned and never give up!

Comment: @Mike anytime, m8! Have you solved your problem? Can I be of further help?

Comment: it's great to have here as i m just a beginner using Tor browser; i tried the "Meek" connections, it worked fine; but now i have a new problem about "fte" & "flashproxy" connections; i tried the configuration according to the instructions from Tor blog; but i failed to get neither "fte" nor "flashproxy" connections; could u help to check? below are the logs of flashproxy failures:

Comment: @ Alexey Vesnin

Comment: Richard Horrocks

Comment: [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
[NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
[NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
[WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 1; recommendation warn; host **********CD395A********* at 0.0.1.0:1) 
[WARN] 1 connections have failed: 
[WARN] 1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE

Comment: @Mike it seems that only Meek transport is working in your case. It's possible, so use it and enjoy the Tor =) Your ISP seems to do a SSL/TLS breaking using MitM, so I do NOT recommend you to log in to ANY of your accounts from there, and also you should use a Perspectives Project for SSL Certificates validation

Comment: @ Alexey Vesnin;
all right, thanks for reminding me about the MitM, and i've already installed Perspective Protect extension on Tor browser; hopes that Meek would survive a loooong time; if not, it would be a disaster to me; o(︶︿︶)o;

Comment: @Mike Anytime! By the way - another must-have addon you should consider using in your situation: [Calomel SSL Validation](https://calomel.org/firefox_ssl_validation.html)

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any evidence of you being the victim of a MITM attack. It appears that your ISP is either blocking *all traffic* to known Tor entry nodes - which would imply they know that your bridges are part of the Tor network - or that they're blocking all *Tor* traffic by looking for  [Tor's traffic signature](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/AChildsGardenOfPluggableTransports).

It might be worth requesting another set of bridges before looking at [pluggable transports](https://www.torproject.org/docs/pluggable-transports.html.en). If you *do* end needing pluggable transports, the recommendations are to try them in the order described in [this](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/how-use-%E2%80%9Cmeek%E2%80%9D-pluggable-transport) official blog post. (It's a year old, but I believe the recommendation still holds true.)

You can presumably ping the bridges because your ISP isn't blocking ICMP traffic.

Comment: thanks man, got a lot help from your links and caught much more information about Tor connections; yeah, what a great Idea of Tor system, full of joys!